# EnsureDeleted without affecting the _EFMigrations table

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

In unit tests I use EnsureDeleted EnsureCreated, it's useful, but after that the database update with new migrations ends with errors, because the _EFMigrations table was truncated by EnsureDeleted method and EF tries to apply all migrations from the beginning.

How can I use the EnsureDeleted method or its equivalent without affecting the _EFMigrations table?

I am using postgres, I understand that you can write your own sql script, but I want to clarify if there is any way to do this by means of .net.
This must be a common problem, but strangely enough I couldn't find anything on google

Comment: I don't see why you would apply migrations after having used `EnsureCreated`. What's the exact scenario?

Comment: I'm developing a service. There is a set of unit tests for the service, the tests run on a test base, which is populated directly from the C# code. To avoid accumulation of entities in the database before initializing the database for running tests I pre-clear it using EnsureDeleted and EnsureCreated.
Then if I change or add some new entities, create migration and apply this migration with database update command I get error like "SQLSTATE[42P07]: relation "_" already exists".

Comment: What I really need is to be able to clear all my tables without touching _EFMigrations